# What is defference between MVC and MVVM Design Pattern of App development

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

As per I know There are MVC design pattern for iOS app Development which Apple follows strongly.
I need to know Some other Design Pattern for iOS like MVVM
What is difference between another pattern for development.
Some Tutorial or Sample code available to understand it better.

Comment: It was little confusing for App development. Here I found I proper explanation
1. [iOS Design Patterns](https://www.raywenderlich.com/46988/ios-design-patterns)
2. [one more](https://www.cs.colorado.edu/~kena/classes/5448/f12/presentation-materials/myrose.pdf)
which explains better ways.
hope this is good.